# React Error: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<{}>' in React.Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

Why would this throw the error below?

```
export default class DeleteModal extends React.Component<DeleteModalProps, void>
```

Error:

**Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<{}>'**

Comment: But why the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

If we don't need state in the component, don't assign it would be fine.

```
React.Component<Props>
```

You can also set the empty object

```
interface State {}

React.Component<Props, State>
```

---

#### Reason

1. If you check the source of `React.Component` [index.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts)

```
interface Component<P = {}, S = {}, SS = any> extends ComponentLifecycle<P, S, SS> { }
```

You can see that it's been defined as empty Object `{}`

2. As for the Typescript document of [void](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#void)

> Declaring variables of type void is not useful because **you can only assign `null` or `undefined` to them**

That's the reason for that error.